# How to force the use of ODBC-version 2.x in C# application

Tags: c#, odbc, honeywell

Odbc-driver is version 2.x, but in Visual Studio, Version 3.x is used.
Need to somehow force application to use Version 2.x
Right now, there is an error: "The driver doesn't support the version of ODBC behavior that the application requested (see SQLSetEnvAttr)."
- but finds no way to tell the application to use an other version

Trying to communicate with a Honeywell System.
They are not known for sharing data - but there is a ODBC-driver, written by someone about 15 years ago.
When running on a Windows 2003 server, and compiled (on that same server) in Visual Studio 2005, the application works.
Same application running on other server: Don't work.
Application compiled (x86) on any other machine: Don't work, not on old server, not on new one.

Finds not properties or methods on the `System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection`, to set version of ODBC to use.

At the moment, you get no "error" running the application:
It connects to the dsn, and user is authenticated.
(Changing the username or password gives an error)
- but no data is fetched.

Doing a trace for the calls to the ODBS driver gives:

> DIAG [IM006] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's
>   SQLSetConnectAttr failed (0)
>
> DIAG [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The driver doesn't
>   support the version of ODBC behavior that the application requested
>   (see SQLSetEnvAttr). (0)
>
> ....
>
> DIAG [IM006] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's
>   SQLSetConnectAttr failed (0)
>
> DIAG [HY096] [Honeywell][ODBC Driver]Info type out of range (1043)
>
> ....
>
> DIAG [HYC00] [Honeywell][ODBC Driver]Driver not capable (1010)

So, since there is no newer driver to use - I need my application to use ODBC 2.x - but it still uses ODBC 3.x.

Comment: You can set the ODBC datasource in Control Panel : Administrative Tools : ODBC Data Source

Answer (score 0):

When you tell VS C# to connect to an ODBC Data Source, it invisibly bridges to ODBC using the Microsoft ADO.NET Provider for ODBC, which wants everything to be as up-to-date as it is.

Your best bet in this situation is to switch to a different ADO.NET Provider that understands you can't always have a new ODBC driver, and will do its best to translate the newer C# ADO.NET API calls to the older ODBC API calls when necessary.  My employer offers a couple of options, one being the [Enterprise Edition Data Access for ODBC Data Sources](https://uda.openlinksw.com/dotnet-odbc-mt/), and the other being the [Virtuoso Universal Server Enterprise Edition](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/middleware/) (functioning as a Virtual DBMS), both of which are available for immediate download, with a free temporary license provided for your testing and evaluation.